# bash loop to read variable in a txt file and do stuffs with them

Tags: bash, loops

hello everyone and good saturday,

I have a text file that looks like that

```
 OTU    sample  Idfolder    linkGenome
TM7_phylum_sp._oral_taxon_488   6405    T1  ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/005/697/215/GCF_005697215.1_ASM569721v1/GCF_005697215.1_ASM569721v1_genomic.fna.gz
TM7_phylum_sp._oral_taxon_957   6405    T2  ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/005/697/565/GCF_005697565.1_ASM569756v1/GCF_005697565.1_ASM569756v1_genomic.fna.gz
Streptococcus_cristatus 6405    SC  https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/385/925/GCF_000385925.1_ASM38592v1/GCF_000385925.1_ASM38592v1_genomic.fna.gz
```

I want to create a loop that 
1) read the file and create subfolder using the name at the third column of my file (Idfolder column); 2)enter in each folder and download a file from the corresponding link located at 4th column of the same txt file

Does anyone have some suggestion on how perform that?
thanks a lot
A.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Start by reading https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 which shows how to read a file a line at a time in bash.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have some suggestion on how perform that?

I wouldn't use a "bash loop" to accomplish this. I'm experimenting with `awk` lately, so I would use that tool and `wget` to download the files:

```
awk 'NR > 1 { system("mkdir -p " $3); system("wget -P " $3 " " $4); }' < in.txt
```

where `in.txt` is your txt file.

Comment: It makes sense to wait until AQ7 has shown what he has been trying to do to solve the problem himself.

Comment: @Cyrus yes, totally. That's the reason why I took the liberty to not use "a bash loop" at all in my solution.